# How can I detect when a flash drive is plugged in under Linux?

Tags: python, linux

How can I detect when a flash drive is plugged in? I'm using a bare Debian installation, without any GUI and want to be notified in my Python script when a new flash drive appears... I know that D-BUS distributes such information, but i dont want to use D-BUS. Is there a more bare access to that information? Shouldn't that be available under /proc or /sys? How can I "connect" to that source?

Bye
falstaff

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read [uevents from kernel](http://lwn.net/Articles/242046/) via a [Netlink](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/netlink.7.html) socket and look for events where `"ACTION"` is `"add"` (you can also watch if a partition from a device was mounted or unmounted, or if a device is being removed). That's as close to the source of events as one can get in user space. As far as I know, this is how `udev` detects inserted removable media.

But probably [using D-Bus/HAL API via Python bingings](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-904706.html) will be much easier (no uevents data parsing, etc). Not sure why you are opposed to this. Since you are using Python, I suspect that resources are not really the issue.

Comment: Thanks! I try your or PeterMmm's approach, im not yet sure if im going to use udev... Well, i use python to programm a prototyp on my machine, which havent any resource issues, but the destination is an embedded device, where i dont want to install all that D-Bus/HAL stuff...

Answer (score 9):

All mayor Linux distros include [udev](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html), that allows you to write custom scripts on hardware events.

Answer (score 4):

If you are targetting an embedded device, then you can run [mdev](http://wildanm.wordpress.com/2007/08/21/mdev-mini-udev-in-busybox/) instead of udev.
Then you can write mdev rules that are quite simple and triggers a script.

Of course you are not directly monitoring from your script, mdev is doing it, but you can launch any command. You can probably do the same thing with udev, but it always looked quite complicated to me.

Answer (score 1):

When an USB device is plugged in syslog writes messages concerning this to  /var/log/messages. The "dmesg" command shows this log. You can check near the end of the log to see which channel the device was attached to, it is usually /dev/sd(letter)(number) depending on the partitions and number of serial disks plugged into the system.

Comment: But for this to work you'd have to poll dmesg, which is very ugly (polling eats performance and interferes with power management).

Comment: I do mention it attaching to /dev/sd** ... Well anyway lots of polling goes on. The previous one mentions some polling too.

Answer (score 0):

/proc/partitions shows all the partitions known to the kernel.

Comment: Yes, but how does this help detect the insertion event? Especially as not all Linux distributions auto-mount by default (though most do).

Comment: Even unmounted partitions show on /proc/partitions - you can poll the file. However, Peter's answer (udev) is probably better since udev is there unless falstaff is using a 2.4 series kernel

Comment: That's true, didn't think of it. udev is still a better solution usually, but if you have to make do with polling, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

I did this using zenity in a script and udev with rule on rhel6 with:

KERNEL=="sd[b-d]", DRIVERS=="usb", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/path/to/script"